# How to Expand and Collapse in HTML5 table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to populate a table in HTML5 dynamically from Odata webservices.I am using JQuery for populating it.I have to also show a child table below each row of the table,when clicking on the first column of each row.I should be able to toggle the table from any row of the Parent table.

I have attached the screenshot of the functionality. Could you please tell me how to achieve it?

**JavaScript**:

```js
var xml;
$.ajax(
    {
        url: "https://192.168.2.133:8080/sap/inv/opu/odata/sap/ZMM_CM_GR_OPENPO/zmm_gr_openpoCollection?$filter=bednr%20eq'0000000112'",

        type: 'GET',
        contentType: "application/xml;charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "",
        cache: false,

        success: function (data) {
            alert("Inside success");
            $(data).find("content").each(function () {
                $(this).find("m\\:properties, properties").each(function () {
                    var $info = $(this);
                    var mat_doc_no = $info.find("d\\:mat_doc_no, mat_doc_no").text();
                    var zvendor = $info.find("d\\:zvendor, zvendor").text();
                    var ebelp_c = $info.find("d\\:ebelp_c, ebelp_c").text();
                    var zz_tmdocno_c = $info.find("d\\:zz_tmdocno_c, zz_tmdocno_c").text();
                    var zz_tmdocno = $info.find("d\\:zz_tmdocno, zz_tmdocno").text();
                    var bedat = $info.find("d\\:bedat, bedat").text();
                    var menge_c = $info.find("d\\:menge_c, menge_c").text();
                    var ebeln = $info.find("d\\:ebeln, ebeln").text();

                    localStorage.setItem("ebeln", ebeln);
                    localStorage.setItem("zz_tmdocno", zz_tmdocno);
                    localStorage.setItem("bedat", bedat);
                    localStorage.setItem("zvendor", zvendor);`enter code here`

                    $('tbody').append('<tr id="test" ><td><input type="checkbox" class = "chcktbl" /></td><td onclick="showGRPODetails()"><u><b>' + ebeln + '</b></u></td><td>' + zz_tmdocno + '</td><td>' + bedat + '</td><td>' + zvendor + '</td></tr>');

                });`enter code here`
            });
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Could not connect URL...!");
        }
    });

function showGRPODetails() {
    $("#testid").toggle();

}
```

Comment: If you could attach your code or the screen shot that'd be great.

Comment: Thanks Pixel :)I have added the code in the above Comment.

Answer (score 0):

Id recommend changing your jQuery from inline to an event

take out this code onclick="showGRPODetails()"

add this either in a function or document ready

```
$('td').click(function () {
   $(this).find('table').slideToggle();
});
```

Id give the dynamic child tables a class of subTable just to make it easier to target

Comment: Thanks J McFee for the reply but I want a child table with columns as below when clicking on the fist column of every row:-The columns are Description,Qty and Unit.

Comment: Hmm not exactly sure then what you are trying to accomplish, sorry I couldnt be of much help